# Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, gulp

So my project structures is I have a `src` and `www` directory in my root `./`, which also contains my `bower.json`, `gulpfile.js`, and `.bowerrc` with the `directory` set to `./www/bower/`.

I have an `index.html` in my `./src` and I've setup a gulp task that pipes it through `wiredep` and out to the `./www` where the bower packages are.

Unfortunately it adds all the dependecies as if it's in the `./src` directory so all of them are prefixed like `../www/bower/` which does work as the final `index.html` ends up in the `www` directory so I fiddled with some of the `wiredep` configuration options like so:

```
gulp.task('bower', function () {
    gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
        cwd: './www',
        bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
        directory: '../.bowerrc'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
});
```

However I get the following error:

```
stream.js:94
    throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at findMainFiles (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\lib\detect-dependencies.js:53:37)
    at D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\lib\detect-dependencies.js:111:17
    at forOwn (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:1301:15)
    at Function.forEach (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:2595:9)
    at detect (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\lib\detect-dependencies.js:312:5)
    at wiredep (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:178:39)
    at Transform._transform (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:217:34)
    at Transform._read (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at Transform._write (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (D:\Dropbox\University\MindFlipDOM\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:238:10)
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've gotten this error before as well. Turns out I was including a dependency in my bower.json file incorrectly. Perhaps you're doing the same?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Also try, this will make sure to download the necessary modules that were missing.

```
bower install
```

Answer (score 14):

Well as far as I can guess, you messed up with bower. Most likely you uninstalled a dependency and forgot to save.

What you should have done:

```
bower uninstall <dependency> --save
```

What you probably did:

```
bower uninstall <dependency>
```

You can solve this issue by bower executing `uninstall <dependency> --save` or if you are unsure of which components you uninstalled, you can edit `bower.json` file and remove components that are not installed. (You can check if a dependency is installed in `bower_componenets` directory)

Comment: Thank you!  I had done bower uninstall ui-bootstrap, I just added --save and everything works again.